# Bugzilla install-module.pl can't find "make" but it's installed and in my path

Tags: perl, installation, bugzilla, make

I'm installing Bugzilla on a new Ubuntu server, and ./checksetup.pl finds one more library I need to install.

So it tells me to run this command:

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Math::Random::Secure
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Using install-module.pl requires that you install "make".
```

Make is installed (apt-get install make) and I know it's in my $PATH (in /usr/bin/) but I still get that error from install-module.pl.

Do I have to do something special to ensure it has the right path or should the path from my shell be used? Is "make" referring to the make I have installed or could it refer to some perl module instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I've just had the same error and fixed it with the below.

```
cpan
o conf make '/usr/bin/make' #or path to your make
o conf commit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it with CPAN:

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan> install Math::Random::Secure
```